# Magento2 Attributes with Options do not show in Product Collections

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I created Attributes with Options in the Product Admin Panel and saves successfully, but the Attribute does not appear in any Product Collections.

```
     public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(12); // fetching only 12 products
        return $collection;


    }
```

```
         $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'is_customoption', [
            'group' => 'Product Details',
            'type' => 'int',
            'sort_order' => 108,
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Custom option',
            'input' => 'select',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => 'Sample\Widget\Model\Config\Source\ProductType',
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable',

        ]);
```

Comment: Welcome mks, it is suggested to use the content area for your description, in there you can add more information as you need.  You have a long description in the Title, which can be moved into the content area.

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to an attribute set manually:

```
Stores > Attribute Set > Default
```

Or from code:

```
'attribute_set' => 'Default',
```